# Eigenfunctions of the exponential of the derivative

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

In the space of smooth functions of one variable is there a way to tell what are the eigenfunctions of the operator $\exp(\partial_x)$, i.e. what is the solution of the eigenvalue problem

$e^{\partial_x}f(x)=af(x)$

seeking for the eigenvectors. I am asking since I don't see the solution to this, whereas asking for the eigenfunctions of $\partial_x$, i.e. solving the equation $\partial_xf(x)=af(x)$ is easily done via $f(x)=be^{cx+d}$.

Can this be done easily or is this highly non-trivial?

Comment: You are aware that $e^{\partial_x}f(x)=f(x+1)$? And more generally, $e^{t\partial_x}f(x)=f(x+t)$ – at least in a formal sense. So your equation is the functional equation $f(x+1)=af(x)$.

Comment: It's the Taylor expansion from $x$ to $x+1$, you're right. So the eigenfunctions look something like $ba^{cx+d}$.

Comment: You can select the eigenfunction to be almost any smooth function in the interval $[0,1]$, just with some restrictions on the end points to fit with the functional equation and give you a smooth solution. Say $f(1)=af(0)$, and similarly for $f'$.